# Creating blank actvity doesn't generate R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I'm working with eclipse Luna in Ubuntu 14.04..
My problem is when I created an "android project", and choose "blank Activity" (minimum API 2.2 target 4.X and compile with 5.1).
Eclipse creates 2 projects, the first one is "appcompat_v7"(with missing R.java) and the second is my project. I've already tried to clean up my project, but eclipse does not allow me to build my project.
And I updated my SDK and ADT to the newest version.

This is a Link to the dropbox with image, because I can't upload image..

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9a6s1a8hqj2tg42/AAAXSR3Q3m8L2IJ5vXvbAMisa?dl=0

My question is why R.java is missing and cause me all these errors..

Comment: Did you try to rebuild your project ? Coz R package formed during build process.

Comment: I don't know why but eclipse doesn't allow me to rebuild it, cause as the image I linked shows the "Build all" option (Project -> Build all) isn't enable.. from my eclipse

Comment: Doing Project->Clean ? and than rebuild your project . It must generate R package.

Comment: that is what I did many times and still doesn't work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the problem!!
Eclipse doesn't compile my R.java file because I didn't install these libs on ubuntu 14.04

"lib32z1" "lib32ncurses5" "lib32bz2-1.0l" and the most important "lib32stdc++6"

after typing

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-10l lib32stdc++6` I solved my problem!!